# Сравнение времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть json, в котором помимо прочего есть время выступления участников. Этот json я разбираю и данные разпихиваю по тегам.

Как мне исходя из из текущего времени и времени в json определить текущего выступающего ?

Может нужно нужно сам json переделать или из таким вариантом можно ?

Это нужно для того чтоб имя текущего участника подсвечивалось красным .

Вот сам json:

```js
{
  "date": {
    "1": {
      "chef": "Иван Пилипенко",
      "anotation": "Применение сухой и влажной ферментации к локальному фермерскому мясу",
      "dolznost": "'Купеческий двор'",
      "date": "Wednesday, November 04, 2015",
      "dataRel": "4 ноября в 11:30",
      "url": "",
      "time": "11:30",
      "dishes ": {
        "1": "Тартар из отлежайшейся говяжьей вырезки на ржаных тостах и хрустящим салатом",
        "2": "Строганина из говяжьего антрекота с клюквой и пармезаном",
        "3": "Филе миньон с белыми грибами",
        "4": "Стейк Рибай на кости с острым ягодным конфитюром"
      }
    },

    "2": {
      "chef": "Владислав Таниславский",
      "anotation": "Рентабельные и гастрономические блюда в ресторане, на примере блюд из тунца",
      "dolznost": "ресторан'Сыто-Пьяно'",
      "date": "Wednesday, November 04, 2015",
      "dataRel": "4 ноября в 13:30",
      "url": "",
      "time": "13:30",
      "dishes ": {
        "": ""
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменять данные нет необходимости. Просто пробегитесь по массиву и если ваша дата больше даты в объекте, и меньше даты в следующем объекте, то значит текущий объект, это то что вы ищете.

Comment: Подскажите как это должно выглядеть синтаксически ? Например я хочу взять свойство chef но только за 04 число ?

Comment: Что бы взять за 4 число, вам достаточно сделать выборку по `date`.